# Amazon Redshift, Unload large Database to single .csv file

Tags: csv, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I want to prepare a large CSV-File from my Redshift Cluster to run a Spark-Job with amazon EMR on it. To load my file from Spark, I need to have the file as one big csv-file in my S3-Bucket, which would be around 100GB large.

I suppose my problems could be solved in two ways,

### 1.) Create large CSV from Redshift

Redshift has an unload-limit of 6.3GB, so if I unload more than that I get many separate files. Can I somehow skip that behavior of redshift OR merge those CSV_parts back to one large CSV?

### 2.) Read sevaral CSVs with spark-

This should barely be a problem, but I have the feeling that this could change the overall runtime of Spark. Do you know if loading from several CSVs make Spark faster or slower?

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't use the spark-redshift connector... It doesn't seem that you've done lots of research concerning the subject.

Comment: You will get much better performance in spark if you use multiple s3 files.you need to research further.